# Modifying weighted gt table based on unweighted data

Tags: r, gtsummary

I am creating multiple weighted tables with multiple variables, and I'm curious about whether weighted values can be changed based on **unweighted** values. Specifically, when n<2, replace cell by NA.

Example data:

```
df <- data.frame(a= c("m","f","f","m", "m", "f", "f"),b= c("g1","g2","g1","g2", "g2", "g2", "g2"),
                 weight = c(1.1, 0.8, 2.2, 4, 3, 0.3, 1.9))

> df
  a  b weight
1 m g1    1.1
2 f g2    0.8
3 f g1    2.2
4 m g2    4.0
5 m g2    3.0
6 f g2    0.3
7 f g2    1.9
```

Table:

```
library(gtsummary)
library(srvyr)

tbl_summary_object <- df %>%
  as_survey_design(1, weight = weight) %>%
  gtsummary::tbl_svysummary(
    missing="no",
    by=a,
    include=-weight,
    label=list(
      b ~ "group"
    ),
    percent="row"
  )
```

[image]

I am looking to modify cells based on **unweighted** cells:

```
> table(df$a, df$b)
   
    g1 g2
  f  1  3
  m  1  2
```

I know that the "by" unweighted variable can be accessed `tbl_summary_object$df_by`. However, I am looking to change each cell based on n<2 in **unweighted** data. Any pointers would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We may use `modify_table_body`

```
library(dplyr)
library(gtsummary)
tbl_summary_object %>%
   modify_table_body(
  ~ .x %>%
    mutate(across(starts_with('stat_'), 
        ~ case_when(readr::parse_number(.x) >1 ~ .x))))
```

-output
[image]

---

Based on the comments, perhaps this helps

```
library(tidyr)
tbl1 <- df %>% 
  count(a, b) %>% 
  mutate(a = recode(a, f = 'stat_1', m = 'stat_2'))  %>% 
  pivot_wider(names_from = a, values_from = n)
tbl_summary_object %>%
  modify_table_body(
  ~ .x %>%
    mutate(across(starts_with('stat_'), 
    ~ case_when(readr::parse_number(.x) > c(NA, tbl1[[cur_column()]]) ~ .x))))
```

Comment: This one is better. Now I remember `modify_table_body`.

Comment: @akrun This is helpful. I have edited the question to emphasize that I am looking to chance cells based on the unweighted data. Is this possible?

Comment: @EML Your `table` gives `1 1 3 2`, whereas `tbl_summary_object$df_by$n_unweighted
[1] 4 3`.  Here, there is no value that is less than 2

Answer (score 1):

We could do it this way:

If I understand you correctly, then we could access our object with `tbl_summary_object[1]$table_body` and manipulate it with an `case_when`, we also use `parse_number` which extracts always the first number and we then can do our comparison n < 2:

```
library(gtsummary)
library(dplyr)
library(readr) # parse_number

tbl_summary_object[1]$table_body  <- tbl_summary_object[1]$table_body %>% 
  mutate(across(c(stat_1, stat_2), ~ case_when(parse_number(.) < 2 ~ "NA",
                                               TRUE ~ .)))

tbl_summary_object
```

[image]