# Editing gt weighted table with multiple variables based on unweighted results

Tags: r, gtsummary

I am trying to edit a **weighted** gt table based on its **unweighted** counterpart. When n < 2, cells should be converted to NA. @akrun posted a useful [response](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73225939/modifying-weighted-gt-table-based-on-unweighted-data) for this question where a single variable was in rows.

Data:

```
df <- data.frame(a= c("m","f","f","m", "m", "f", "f"),b= c("g1","g2","g1","g2", "g2", "g2", "g2"),
                 c=c("c", "c", "c", "d", "c", "e", "e"),
                 d =c("t", "s", "t", "t", "s", "s", "t"),
                 weight = c(1.1, 0.8, 2.2, 4, 3, 0.3, 1.9))
```

Table:

```
library(gtsummary)
library(srvyr)
library(dplyr)

tbl_summary_object <- df %>%
  as_survey_design(1, weight = weight) %>%
  gtsummary::tbl_svysummary(
    missing="no",
    by=a,
    include=-weight,
    label=list(
      b ~ "group",
      c ~ "group2",
      d ~ "group3"
    ),
    percent="row"
  )

tbl_summary_object
```

[image]

Unweighted table:

```
tbl1 <- df %>%
  gather(key, value, b,c, d) %>%
  group_by(a, value) %>%
  summarise(n=n()) %>%
  spread(a, n) %>%
  dplyr::ungroup() %>%
  arrange(match(value, c("g1", "g2", "c", "d", "e", "s", "t"))) %>%
  rename(stat_1=f, stat_2=m) %>%
  add_row( value=NA,stat_1=NA, stat_2=NA, .before=3) %>%
  add_row( value=NA,stat_1=NA, stat_2=NA, .before=7)

 > tbl1
# A tibble: 9 × 3
  value stat_1 stat_2
  <chr>  <int>  <int>
1 g1         1      1
2 g2         3      2
3 NA        NA     NA
4 c          2      2
5 d         NA      1
6 e          2     NA
7 NA        NA     NA
8 s          2      1
9 t          2      2
```

Answer (score 0):

I found a relatively straightforward solution.

#### Create weighted table

```
tbl_summary_object <- df %>%
  as_survey_design(1, weight = weight) %>%
  gtsummary::tbl_svysummary(
    missing="no",
    by=a,
    include=-weight,
    label=list(
      b ~ "group",
      c ~ "group2",
      d ~ "group3"
    ),
    percent="row"
  ) %>%
  as_gt()
```

#### Create unweighted table

```
tbl_summary_object_uw <- df %>%
  gtsummary::tbl_summary(
    missing="no",
    by=a,
    include=-weight,
    label=list(
      b ~ "group",
      c ~ "group2",
      d ~ "group3"
    ),
    percent="row"
  ) %>%
  as_gt() 

# table with raw n
raw_n <- tbl_summary_object_uw[["_data"]] %>%
  mutate(across(contains("stat"), 
                ~str_replace(., " \\s*\\([^\\)]+\\)", "")))
```

#### Convert cells <2 to NA

```
for(c in 1:2) { 
  for(r in 1:nrow(raw_n)) {
  tbl_summary_object[["_data"]][6:7][r,c] <- 
    ifelse(raw_n[6:7][r,c] < 2, NA, tbl_summary_object[["_data"]][6:7][r,c])
  }
}

> tbl_summary_object
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

An `dplyr`/`tidyr` option where you join both tables and `rowwise` check if the values meet the conditions otherwise remove them like this:

```
library(gtsummary)
library(srvyr)
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

tbl_summary_object <- df %>%
  as_survey_design(1, weight = weight) %>%
  gtsummary::tbl_svysummary(
    missing="no",
    by=a,
    include=-weight,
    label=list(
      b ~ "group",
      c ~ "group2",
      d ~ "group3"
    ),
    percent="row"
  )

tbl_summary_object

tbl1 <- df %>%
  gather(key, value, b,c, d) %>%
  group_by(a, value) %>%
  summarise(n=n()) %>%
  spread(a, n) %>%
  dplyr::ungroup() %>%
  arrange(match(value, c("g1", "g2", "c", "d", "e", "s", "t"))) %>%
  rename(stat_1=f, stat_2=m) %>%
  add_row( value=NA,stat_1=NA, stat_2=NA, .before=3) %>%
  add_row( value=NA,stat_1=NA, stat_2=NA, .before=7)

tbl_summary_object[1]$table_body <- tbl_summary_object[1]$table_body %>% 
  left_join(., tbl1, by = c("label" = "value")) %>%
  rowwise() %>%
  mutate(across(stat_1.x: stat_2.y),
                stat_1 = ifelse(stat_1.y < 2, NA, stat_1.x),
                stat_2 = ifelse(stat_2.y < 2, NA, stat_2.x)) %>%
  ungroup() %>%
  dplyr::select(-matches(".x$|.y$"))
                
tbl_summary_object
```

Output:

[image]